# Hide tabbar on one viewcontroller Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a tabbed application in Xcode. I don't want my user to see the tab bar unless he logs in. My `viewcontroller`'s name is `Login`

Comment: Add iOS as additional tag to boost visibility.

Answer (score 1):

First present the login view controller which handles the input and validation of user credentials.

In case of success, present the tab bar controller either by replacing window root view controller (initially the login controller) or by pushing the tab bar controller on navigation stack (in this case the navigation controller is the initial view controller).